# How to fit the webpage in any screen resolution

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

How to fit my web page in any screen resolution, My monitor screen size is 23 inches and my screen resolution is 1920x1080. My theme looks like this on the browser:

[image: See Image]

I want it to fit the display in any screen resolution just like viewing on screen of 1366x768 it looks like this on the desktop version only:

[image: See Image]

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Atanas i dont know with my boss i just follow what he wants, he wanted like this https://www.staples.com

Comment: Here is what to tell him:
It's better for the site to be responsive! If the screen size is smaller and the site is not responsive, then the text and images will become too small! Now it's the best possible!

Answer (score 0):

It's better for the site to be responsive! If the screen size is smaller and the site is not responsive, then the text and images will become too small! Now it's the best possible!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the classes and properties of the designing languages you are using inspite of making of your own for e.g if u are using bootstrap for creating web pages then use its class like if you are using  then its better to use col-lg,col-md,col-sm rather than giving your own styles.
This will create a huge difference while viewing the web page as the web page will be responsive and fit on every screen.